# Unable to install openssl in AIX due to "cc: unrecognized option"

Tags: gcc, openssl, makefile, aix

So I installed openssl in one of the 3 aix servers but it just wouldn't work in the other 2 servers.
I'm trying to install openssl-1.0.1h on AIX.

**Step 1**: I ran the config file -

```
./config -–prefix=/appl/peoplesoft/apache/openssl
```

Output: a Makefile is generated.

**Step 2**: run the make command.
Output of command make:

```
$ make  
making all in crypto...
        ( echo "#ifndef MK1MF_BUILD";  echo '  /* auto-generated by crypto/Makefile for crypto/cversion.c */';  echo '  #define CFLAGS "cc -DOPENSSL_THREADS -qthreaded -D_THREAD_SAFE -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -q32 -O -DB_ENDIAN -qmaxmem=16384 -qro -qroconst -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DAES_ASM"';  echo '  #define PLATFORM "aix-cc"';  echo "  #define DATE \"`LC_ALL=C LC_TIME=C date`\"";  echo '#endif' ) >buildinf.h
        cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -qthreaded -D_THREAD_SAFE -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -q32 -O -DB_ENDIAN -qmaxmem=16384 -qro -qroconst -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DAES_ASM -c cryptlib.c
cc: unrecognized option '-qthreaded'
cc: unrecognized option '-q32'
cc: unrecognized option '-qmaxmem=16384'
cc: unrecognized option '-qro'
cc: unrecognized option '-qroconst'
```

I don't know what's wrong.
I'm using gcc version 4.2.0 and cc has a softlink to gcc.
Should I try copying the Makefile file from the server where it works?

Comment: gcc doesn't really understands xlc's options...

Comment: use `./Configure -–prefix=/appl/peoplesoft/apache/openssl  ... aix-gcc` or `./Configure -–prefix=/appl/peoplesoft/apache/openssl  ... aix-gcc`

Comment: Here `...` means any compiler/linker option you can make up, eg: -maix32/-maix64 -mtune=native -pthread -lpthreads -Wl,-brtl etc

Answer (score 1):

I'll try the previous comments: gcc doesn't really understands xlc's options, use either this:

```
./Configure -–prefix=/appl/peoplesoft/apache/openssl -maix32 \
... aix-gcc
```

or

```
./Configure -–prefix=/appl/peoplesoft/apache/openssl -maix64 \
... aix64-gcc
```

Where ... is the set of compiler/linker options you can think of, eg:

```
-mtune=native -pthread -lpthreads -Wl,-brtl
```

Comment: Bravo! It worked. And I also learnt few new things. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Open config file , for AIX and locate the "favor vendor cc over gcc"

Change this: (replace cc with gcc for AIX)

```
if [ "${SYSTEM}" = "AIX" ]; then        # favor vendor cc over gcc
    (cc) 2>&1 | grep -iv "not found" > /dev/null && CC=cc
fi
```

to this :

```
if [ "${SYSTEM}" = "AIX" ]; then        # favor vendor cc over gcc
    (cc) 2>&1 | grep -iv "not found" > /dev/null && CC=gcc
fi
```

And rerun your configuration ...